# Unable to change Navbar Color

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I tried so many things to change the navbar colour such as

[Android lollipop change navigation bar color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27839105/android-lollipop-change-navigation-bar-color)

[android change navigation bar color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41303597/android-change-navigation-bar-color)

[How to change system navigation bar color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27348336/how-to-change-system-navigation-bar-color)

Nothing works

I added the item to `styles.xml`  - using Android 8.1

```
<item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/theme_color</item>
```

Anyone knows what is the best way to do this in Xamarin.Android

UPDATE: I tried the following code in my style file

```
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
  </style>

  <style name="DrawerArrowStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="color">@color/red</item>
  </style>

  <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
  </style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> While fixing another issue I had to change and minimum API level to
>   Lollipop and noticed that
>   `<itemname="android:navigationBarColor">@color/theme_color</item>`
>   started working when minimum API level is set to Lollipop.

So I think for some reason Xamarin requires to use use Minimum API version Lollipop for this to work

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

You need to create a new style for drawer toggle **like this**:

```
<style name="DrawerArrowStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
    <item name="color">@color/white_color</item>
</style>
```

And add this to your preferable style.

```
<style name="NoActionbarTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
</style>
```

And finally use `NoActionbarTheme` theme in manifest file within your Activity.

Hope it will help you.

Comment: It does not work - I updated the answer with your code